# Retrieve form value after redirecting to different URL in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

Suppose i have a form which asks for `username` only and has a button called `login`. The URL for the current scenario is localhost:8080/beforelogin .

Once I click on `login`, the form redirects to localhost:8080/loginsuccess . I have to show the message *WELCOME USER* (the `username` was entered on localhost:8080/beforelogin) .

I can fetch `username` but because of the page refresh (redirect to different URL),  I cannot show it on different URL.

My code on client side

```
$('.login').on('click', function()     // login is class of button Login
    {
        document.location.href = "/loginsuccess";    
        var username=$('.username_entered').val());   // username_entered is class username entered before login.
        $('.user-name-to-publish').html(username);    // user-name-to-publish is the class where i have to publish username entered before login
    });
```

I can explain more if I am not clear.

Comment: you can alert the welcome text before sending the request to the server as no validation is going on I think or is there a server side validation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok one way of doing this would be passing the entered username along as a parameter in the url.

```
$('.login').on('click', function()     // login is class of button Login
    {
        var username=$('.username_entered').val());
        document.location.href = "/loginsuccess?username=" + username;
    });
```

and then fetch the username in the loginsuccess page. Check this blog for more info:

http://www.sitepoint.com/url-parameters-jquery/

Another way would be to post it to the server and let the server redirect your user to the loginsuccess page and then have the server send the username.